# How can I make my routes that start with /home always direct to the home controller and index action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "home/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This works fine and directs to the home controller Index action where the user enters /home

Is there a way that I can ALWAYS make it direct to the Index action if the user enters:

/home/xxx or
/home/xxx/xxx

Where xxx can be anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just remove the `{action}` part from your route definition so that the action is always `Index`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "home/{anything}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Would this work for the two combinations of /home/xx and /home/xx/xx ?

Comment: Yes, it will work. The `{id}` route token is optional in this route.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the {action} from the url and keep it as a default value then it should work fine.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "home/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

In this scenario action will ALWAYS be Index...

Answer (score 0):

Try this to catch every possible route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "home/{*url}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } }
);
```

Comment: Would this also catch /home/x/x/x ?

Comment: it should, but you better double test it. I have not the possibility at the moment